# jquery / css: make text inside div scroll horizontally like a news ticker no plugin

Tags: jquery, css

anyone have some tips on how to make text inside a div scroll horizontally from right to left in a "news ticker" fashion without having to use a plugin.  Here is an example of exactly what I'm trying to accomplish (this is a plugin solution: http://www.maaki.com/scrollingText.html).

Comment: Have you looked into the html tag `marquee`?

Comment: no and i don't plan to use a deprecated html tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a quick solution to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mTMw/8/

```
var marquee = $('div.marquee');
marquee.each(function() {
    var mar = $(this),indent = mar.width();
    mar.marquee = function() {
        indent--;
        mar.css('text-indent',indent);
        if (indent < -1 * mar.children('div.marquee-text').width()) {
            indent = mar.width();
        }
    };
    mar.data('interval',setInterval(mar.marquee,1000/60));
});​
```

Using the `text-indent` css property, you can do this rather simply.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. What if I did not want any space between the interval, so no blank interval at all?

Answer (score 11):

I recently solved this with CSS keyframe animations.

Essentially your ticker needs a wrapper div with overflow hidden on it.
The tickers contained items should display inline-block so they are in a line:

```
<div class="ticker-wrap">
    <div class="ticker">
        <div class="ticker__item">Letterpress chambray brunch.</div>
        <div class="ticker__item">Vice mlkshk crucifix beard chillwave meditation hoodie asymmetrical Helvetica.</div>
        <div class="ticker__item">Ugh PBR&B kale chips Echo Park.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.ticker-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 4rem;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
    padding-left: 100%; // offsets items to begin
}

.ticker {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 100%; // taken from container as display inline-block
}

.ticker__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}
```

I have [a demo](http://codepen.io/lewismcarey/full/GJZVoG/) that uses the css keyframe animation to then transform the content all the way from one side to the other infinitely. n.b. Vendor prefixed versions not shown.

```
@keyframes ticker {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The only tweak you need is to set the animation duration and apply it to .ticker.

```
.ticker {
    animation-name: ticker;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 25s; // tweak based on number of items/desired speed
}
```

You can see the [full demo](http://codepen.io/lewismcarey/full/GJZVoG/)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. You can also pause the ticker on hover with this css: `.ticker:hover { -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; -moz-animation-play-state: paused; -o-animation-play-state: paused; animation-play-state: paused; }`

Comment: I've had a go at using this... but the infinite loop doesn't happen... it just stops after third entry and restarts!

Comment: how to make it scrolling from bottom to top? i tried with changing some attributes, but didn't work

Comment: I got this to work, but when it reaches the end of my list, it resets and doesnt just keep flowing, so you get a big blank space when it comes back around.

Answer (score 0):

To make it scrolling from bottom to top, replace the left attribute with top. That's worked for me

Comment: This should be parked as a comment unless you provide more details to OPs question

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this

```
<div id="scrollcontainer" style="postion:relative; overflow:hidden; width:100%;">
  <span id="scrolltext" style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">this is the scrolling text</span>
</div>
```

and a js function

```
function scroll() {
  $('#scrolltext').css('left', $('#scrollcontainer').width());
  $('#scrolltext').animate({
    left: '-='+($('#scrollcontainer').width()+$('#scrolltext').width())
  }, 2000, function() {
    scroll();
  });
}

scroll();
```

tested. can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrW5q/85/

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, unfortunately, the nature of absolute positioning causes the container to not take up the space it actually uses, so be aware of that!

Comment: thats where the white-space:nowrap comes in :) I improved and tested and updated the code above. regards

Comment: how to make it  scrolling from bottom to top?